Simple objects in the direct sum of abelian categories
I'm not familiar with the direct sum of abelian categories.
I have a question:
Let $A$ and $B$ be algebras. Let $\mathrm{Mod}_A$ be the category of left $A-$module and $\mathrm{Mod}_B$ be the category of left $B-$module.  If we define the direct sum of two abelian category $\mathrm{Mod}_A$ and  $ \mathrm{Mod}_B$ $$\mathrm{Mod}_A\oplus\mathrm{Mod}_B.$$
How can we know the simple object $V$ in $\mathrm{Mod}_A\oplus\mathrm{Mod}_B$?
Is $V$ the direct sum of $V_1\oplus V_2$ where $V_1$ is the simple module of $\mathrm{Mod}_A$ and $V_2\oplus V_2$ where $V_1$ is the simple module of $\mathrm{Mod}_B$ ?
If not, can we get a specific characterization for simple object in $\mathrm{Mod}_A\oplus\mathrm{Mod}_B$?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

The direct sum of abelian categories is in particular the product of these categories (in the $1$-category of appropriately sized categories), and limits in a product of categories are computed componentwise. In our case, this means that $(V_1,V_2)\oplus(W_1,W_2)\cong (V_1\oplus W_1, V_2\oplus W_2)$ for $V_1, W_1\in\mathrm{Mod}_A$ and $V_2, W_2\in\mathrm{Mod}_B$. This gives you that an object $(V_1,V_2)$ is simple in $\mathrm{Mod}_A\oplus\mathrm{Mod}_B$ iff one of $V_1$ or $V_2$ is simple in $\mathrm{Mod}_A$ or $\mathrm{Mod}_B$, and the other is $0$. It is false that $(V_1,V_2)$ is simple if both $V_1$ and $V_2$ are, because you have the decomposition $(V_1,V_2)\cong(V_1,0)\oplus(0,V_2)$.

Thanks! I have a new question : I think  it can be extended to the countable situation. That is if $\mathrm{Mod}=\oplus _{i\in I}\mathrm{Mod}\left( A_i \right) $, then $V=\left( V_1,V_2,\cdots \right) $ where only a finite number of them are not zero is a simple object in $\mathrm{Mod}$ if and only if $V_j\ne 0$ for one $j\in I$ and the other are all $0$. Is it true?

Yes (if you include the requirement that $V_j$ itself is also simple), the same argument works.
